# Packages/Symbols not found in new model (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, module

I'm working on a project, where I added a new module, where a JmsProducer send messages to a queue. 
After clean/install worked without any errors.

But when I start the application it says that all classes and packages of this module don't exist.

I looked the last 2 days for the solution to it. Everything which were listed on Stackoverflow etc. didn't work for me. 
These points where tried so far:

- Invalidate Caches
- Reimport Maven-Project
- delete target and compile again
- make sure that the dependencies of the module is in the parent (yes it does exist there)
- check the git project again with your branch
- clean/install maven
- etc.

For short I can't post any code because of the company Terms of Service. 
But my co-workers couldn't help me. Everything seems fine by them. 
The branch don't work on there machines too.

I hope so much, that some1 can help me out. There is also a little frustration right now.

Thank you.

Comment: Am I got you right that only one branch doesn't work on all machines? Does it work if you run it outside IDE?

Comment: Without posting code, I doubt that someone can help you here. Especially when you don't even say what kind of application you are building, how you start it and what the exact error message is.

Comment: @y.bedrov the project has multiple modules and they work fine. the creation was 1:1 to other modules. 

@ JFMeier its a project where u can make nodes, marks on different document types (word, openoffice and pdf) and share it with colleagues. and the new module should send logs via JMS on a queue which will be consumed and written in a database.

Comment: What kind of application are you starting? If there is an issue during the start the packaging of the application is faulty ...

Comment: So is it a jar or war or something else? How do you start it? What is the error message?

Comment: the application starts via tomcat which starts the artifact-war file of the project. 

The Error message just say "java: package ... does not exist" but the class where i use the classes of the packages nothing show up with the red underlines etc.@JFMeier